# Nsmutablearray insertobject atindex but move down already inserted objects

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I wanted to ask if the following scenario is somehow possible to happen.
I have an Nsmutablearray and i have in it 5 objects. I load the Nsmutablearray on an uitableview. I want to insert a new object at the top of the other five objects but also move down all the previously inserted objects down by one. let me give you an example

```
0 one
1 two
2 three
3 four
4 five
```

i want to result like this after the new object inserted on the top

```
0 six
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

This method of `NSMutableArray` is what you are looking for.

> If index is already occupied, the objects at index and beyond are shifted by adding **1** to their indices to make room.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as the correct because Francesco mentioned the following fact...If index is already occupied, the objects at index and beyond are shifted by adding 1 to their indices to make room.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is: `- [NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]`.

In your example, the index would be 0.