# Add an object in a specific position of a NSArray - iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Please suggestion only for NSArray.

```
NSArray *addressAry = [[arr1 valueForKey:@"var_offline_address"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"$#$"];
for (int i = 0; i<=addressAry.count; i++) {
   NSString *str = [addressAry objectAtIndex:i];
   if (str containsString:@"NA") {
        NSString *strChange;
        strChange = @"Address Not Available";
```

Comment: Try adding some description and be specific about your problem. Just putting some code doesn't help.

Comment: `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`? `NSArray` can't be modified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nsmutablearray insertobject atindex but move down already inserted objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247941/nsmutablearray-insertobject-atindex-but-move-down-already-inserted-objects)

Comment: Please suggestion only for NSArray without use NSMutableArray.

Comment: @Vipin Like the_UB said: `NSArray` is immutable. You can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
[myMutableArray insertObject:myObject atIndex:42];
```

To add an object to the front of the array, use 0 as the index:

```
[myMutableArray insertObject:myObject atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSMutableArray`. It has a method called:

```
- (void)insertObject:(ObjectType)anObject  atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

Like:

```
[yourMutableArray insertObject: theObject atIndex: theIndex];
```

As it describes:

> If index is already occupied, the objects at index and beyond are shifted by adding 1 to their indices to make room.

For more info [see the official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/insertObject:atIndex:).

Comment: can I add object at indexpath only for NSArray?

Comment: @Vipin > No you can't. NSArray is not editable. You have to use NSMutableArray.